# Does the emperor want to bring Horus Lupercal back?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I had a conversation with someone recently who said the Emperor had someone try to clone Horus Lupercal, but there was no soul to put in the body as Horus has been totally destroyed, which my associate said just made The Emperor angry (I assume the person attempting to clone Horus knew by psychic communication?) On further conversation it was revealed it would be possible for the cabal to travel back in time and fetch Horus from the past, back before he was destroyed; however, she indicated that even if they knew it is The Will Of The Emperor they are still disinclined to do so as they have gotten used to hunting Chaos (and still consider Horus to have fallen to The Ruinous Powers???) and would not follow even a direct command from their Emperor to do so.

How much of the above is canon? Are people inclined to believe the truth of it?

(Footnote: Odd question, perhaps, but if Horus Lupercal were to be brought back, could something be done with The Enunica to bind Horus until such a time as He could be freed from the grip of Chaos?)

Comment: I don't think any of this is true. Who did he ask and when did he ask them? The Emperor was interned in the Golden Throne almost immediately after his battle with Horus. He hasn't spoken to anyone since then, so nothing your friend told you really makes any sense. Sounds like fan fiction to me.

Comment: The answer I have received seems to indicate psychic communication. The Emperor is ever present.

Comment: There was a clone of Horus! One of the fallen Legions, the Emperor Children if I remember well, made a clone of Horus. However, Abbadon found it and destroyed it, arguing that Horus had failed and the Chaos didn't need a new Horus (the source is any old enough version of the Chaos Space Marines. I don't know if this is still canon.). This is for the same reason that the Sons of Horus were renamed by Abbadon as the Black Legion.

Comment: Are you also saying that the Cabal is working for the Emperor? This is doubtful since their goal is to destroy mankind, in order to kill the Chaos Gods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have stated I think your friend is wrong and possibly confusing a number of different stories and plots.

The Cabal were actively working against the Emperor. The book 'Legion' describes how they actually wanted Horus to win the Heresy and destroy the Emperor in a scheme that would ultimately destroy the Chaos gods. And as far as I'm aware the Emperor never had direct contact with the Cabal and I'm not sure if he even knew of their existence as they were a secretive group (though he did speak with John Grammaticus, though I believe this was before he became an agent of the Cabal).

Maybe your friend has gotten a few different story arcs mixed up e.g the Cabal being involved in trying to shape the Heresy in 'Legion' and Fabius Bile (of the Emperor's Children as noted in the comments) trying to clone Horus - a clone which Abaddon destroyed (again as noted in the comments).

For what it's worth Fabius Bile did try and clone other Primarchs as well -under the orders of Fulgrim he attempted to clone Ferrus Manus a number of times and he'd also cloned himself, as well as stealing the blood of Sanguinius in an attempt to clone the Emperor. You can read more about Bile here http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Fabius_Bile

Comment: Nice answer. What happened to the clones of Ferrus Manus? We know that most of Fabius Bile's experiments to improve Space Marines turn into abominations.

Comment: Fulgrim killed them all as far as I know.He was playing a chess-like game with the clones,and kept trying to tempt clone Ferrus to join the Heresy. At this point Ferrus would 'remember' what had happened and fight Fulgrim. Fulgrim would always complain to Fabius that he never got Ferrus' hands right. Which was understandable as I believe they were covered in silver potentially from a C'tan(not 100% sure on this).The stories have so far not revealed if a 'perfect' clone was ever made and if it was allowed to live.But the room was originally described as full of various clone Ferrus corpses

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it from a Codex? Or from a novel?

Comment: It's from one of the black library Horus Heresy collections, it's just a short story, I'll see if I can dig out the title of the book and the story in question as I think you can buy some of them individually as ebooks

Comment: The book is called "Death and Defiance" and the name of the particular story is "Imperfect"  http://www.blacklibrary.com/all-products/imperfect-ebook.html - hope that helps. It also seems to be part of this Anthology http://www.blacklibrary.com/horus-heresy/hh-feat/the-last-phoenix-pb.html and a number of others